# How can I open or view a file with extension .bob?

Tags: image, file, image-processing, 3d, file-type

Our interactive development company received assets from a client with extension ".bob". They are supposed to be some sort of 3D assets, or possibly 3D renders. We have no idea how to open or view these files.

We are on OSX, however if there is a Windows solution, we have access to that as well.

What program can we use with these files?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this kind of situations, aside from using google or other search engines, is to ask your client what program they used to create these files.

A quick google search seems to indicate an uncommon Raytracer bitmap image format.
http://www.openwith.org/file-extensions/bob/1134
Can be opened with XnView.

More information on it's origin is here:
http://www.fileformat.info/format/vividbob/egff.htm

It is mentioned here: http://www.pixedit.com/fileformats.aspx#73862070-8a21-4446-a3f0-f79f57cbbffb
That .bob files could be opened and converted with PixEdit.
http://www.pixedit.com/

Comment: I have already searched quite a bit. There is very little info about this format.

Comment: I have also already tried XnView, I get an error when attempting to open the files.

Comment: The client is simply passing these assets along, and is not being very forthcoming about their origin.

Comment: Looks like it are 3D assets and not just renders. You can use the file organization and details from the fileformat link. The format is also described in the book: Photorealism and Ray Tracing in C. You might want to buy that.